# unable to exit my process after completion. NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sftp

I'm working on a Node JS program to connect to a remote SFTP server to copy log files. I'm using this NPM package. [ssh2-sftp-client](https://github.com/theophilusx/ssh2-sftp-client)

```
const main = () => {
  const servers = ['server list'];
  servers.forEach((s) => {
    const sftp = new Client();
    // Connect to the server
    sftp.connect({
      host: s,
      port: '22',
      username: '',
      password: '',
    }).then(() => logger.log(`Connected to ${s}`))
      // get list of directories
      .then(() => sftp.list(rootLogPath))
      .then((dirs) => {
        dirs.forEach((d) => {
          const target = createTargetDirectory(d.name);
          // list all files in the directory
          sftp.list(`${rootLogPath}/${d.name}`)
            .then((files) => {
              // filter only today's files
              const todayFiles = files.filter((f) => f.type === '-' && moment().format('MMDDYYYY') === moment(f.modifyTime).format('MMDDYYYY'));
              // copy today's files into target
              todayFiles.forEach((f) => {
                sftp.get(`${rootLogPath}/${d.name}/${f.name}`, `${target}/${f.name}`)
                  .then(() => logger.log(`Copied ${f.name} from ${d.name} located on ${s}`));
              });
            });
        });
        return sftp.end();
      })
      .catch(() => logger.log(`Connection to ${s} failed`));
  });
};

main();
```

The code is working as expected but the problem is I'm not able to terminate the session. The program just waits after its completed the copy files operation. The `sftp.end()` call is prematurely closing out connection before copying is complete. If I remove that program just waits after copy is completed.

I'm not sure where to write the `sftp.end()` line to terminate the program.

EDIT 1: Updated code using Promise.all and making use of async/await now.

Split my code into pieces and now making use of async/await for better readability. Program now ends fine. no more waiting or hanging but the problem is files are not copied. I see a console message "Copied files from source directory".

```
const copyTodayFiles = async (src) => {
  try {
    let fileList = await sftp.list(`${rootLogPath}/${src}`);
    fileList = fileList.filter(
      (f) => f.type === '-' && moment().format('MMDDYYYY') === moment(f.modifyTime).format('MMDDYYYY'),
    );
    const target = createTargetDirectory(src);

    if (target) {
      fileList.forEach(async (f) => {
        try {
          await sftp.get(`${rootLogPath}/${src}/${f.name}`, `${target}/${f.name}`);
          logger.log(`Copied ${f.name}`);
        } catch (error) {
          logger.log(`Failed to copy ${f.name}`);
        }
      });
      console.log(`Copied files from ${src}`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    logger.log(`Failed to read files from ${src}`);
    logger.log(error);
  }
};

const workOn = async (server) => {
  sftp = new Client();

  const config = {
    host: server,
    port: '22',
    username: '',
    password: '',
  };

  try {
    await sftp.connect(config);
    logger.log(`Connection to ${server} is successful.`);
    const logDir = await sftp.list(rootLogPath);
    Promise.all(logDir.map((d) => copyTodayFiles(d.name))).then(() => sftp.end());
    // logDir.forEach(async (d) => copyTodayFiles(d.name));
  } catch (error) {
    logger.log(`Connection to ${server} failed.`);
    logger.log(error);
  }
};

const main = () => {
  const servers = ['server list'];
  Promise.all(servers.map((s) => workOn(s)));
};

main();
```

Comment: you are using a `forEach` loop which executes synchronously and doesn't save function return values, and immediately call `sftp.end()` when `forEach` returns. Look up questions on the use of `forEach` in asynchronous code before proceeding. :-)

Comment: thank you. will look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, when you have a "chain" of promises (`a.then(() => b.then(() =>...`) and you want to do something at the end of them, you simply add that thing to the last `.then` callback.

However, if you're making *multiple* promises, you need to wait until all of them are finished, which you can do using `Promise.all` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(...
```

To do that, you'll need to convert all of your `forEach` calls to instead be `map` calls, which return the promises they create.  Once you do that, the `map` operation will return an array of those promises, which you can use with `Promise.all`.

Comment: split my code into functions and using async/await now. Please see EDIT 1

Comment: That still won't work unfortunately.  If you want to do things that way you'll need to switch to the language level `for(let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {` style.  You have to keep in mind that even when you use `async` on a function, what that's really saying is "this function returns a promise".  `.forEach` does not know what to do with a promise, so you either need to not use it, or use `map` instead and pass the array of promises that come back to `Promise.all`.

Comment: this helped me to fix my problem. Thank you !